# When I fit my data with GEV, I got positive parameter, but when I fit it with GPD, I got negative parameter?

Tags: extreme-value, heavy-tailed

[image]
My data is the total annual precipitation in Australia. My purpose is to observe the extreme precipitation on the right end tail. When I fit my data with Generalized Extreme Value, I got positive shape parameter (xi) which means it has a relatively heavy tail and no upper bound, but when I fit it with Generalized Pareto Distribution, I got negative shape parameter, which means the distribution is bounded. Both of the distributions have > 0.05 p-val for the Cramer-Von Mises test. 
Based on what I know, the value of the shape parameter of GEV and GPD is relatively similar. Even when I try to increase my threshold, I still get negative shape parameter for the GPD distribution. Is it possible to have different shape parameter for GEV and GPD?

Comment: You need to show much, much more detail before we can advise. Which parameters and what else is going on? Can you show data or graphs?

Comment: I used the total rainfall annually in Springwood, Australia data, and I have also uploaded the graphs. I am not sure because of the downward trend of the mean excess plot.

Comment: Depends in part on what you plan next to do. GPD can't catch the fact that the distribution has two tails..GEV looks better to me in general.

Comment: Do the mean excess plot will influence the GEV shape parameter? Or is it only influence the GPD shape parameter? In a way that if the mean excess plot trend is downward then the GPD shape parameter is negative.

Comment: And also, actually I want to observe the tail behavior on the right tail, so is it better to use the GPD or the GEV? Because I want to see the maximum extreme rainfall on the right tail

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow your English fully. Some people say that if you are trying the model the far right tail, it doesn't matter what is happening on the left. But I can't see that GPD works better. (I can't easily read all your output, and I have never used any of those functions.)

Comment: With the GPD, you should use *all* the rainfalls above the chosen threshold $u$, while you seem to use only rainfalls within the annual maxima series. Usually the excesses $Y_i-u$ have a mode at zero, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. Not all users of this site are native speakers of English and acronyms are notoriously hard to translate. But I am a native speaker of English and I don't know what you mean.